# Rails4 - How to receive and send JSON data securely through Ajax and store it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page(like https://www.helloabc.com/han.html) that is loaded inside an iframe on an app of different domain. I added the following to enable loading the page in an iframe to remove the error("Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options").

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers['X-Frame-Options'] = "ALLOW-FROM https://xyz.com"
```

The iframe page sends data through ajax json to another page as follows .

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.helloabc.com/hello',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        "url"  : hjurl,
        "data"   : senddatavar
      },
      success: function(a){
          console.log("success");
          console.log(a.message);
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
      console.log("error");
      }
    });
```

I receive 200 ok in my iframe page.

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/hello" host=www.helloabc.com request_id=ac3ed869-75cc-484f-94ea-65ea2fccbb9e fwd="117.203.154.1" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=900
app[web.1]: Started POST "/hello" for 117.203.154.1 at 2014-11-07 16:45:29 +0000
app[web.1]: Processing by HomePageController#hellojson as JSON
app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"url"=>"https://abc.yupp.com/hs/_/krki5gea", "data"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"937bacaeb0f928", "person"=>{"id"=>"1984762436", "dName"=>"zzzzz", "image"=>{"url"=>"https://sbc/photo.jpg"}}, }}}
app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I am new to rails. I don't know how to grab this data and store it. And I dont  know how to do it the right way.
Can anyone please share what is the best practice to send data through ajax securely and store it?

Comment: in your HomePageController hellojson you have access to `params` variable, which stores all the data you are looking for, is that what you are asking?

Comment: oh I can access them using params? Thanks. I will check and try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used params in the following controller to get the data and save it in table

```
  def hellojson

  m = Haout.new      

  m.url = params["url"]
  m.image = params["data"]["0"]["person"]["image"]["url"]
```

then i used conditions and based on conditions I did m.save and m.update_attributes

It is secure if https is used